# How to solve or approximate $\int \cdots \int \prod \textrm{exp} \left\{ -b_{t} \cos\left(\theta_{t}\right) \right\} d\theta_1 \cdots \theta_T$??

Tags: integration, exponential-function, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to solve the following integration for $N>2$. Any suggestion how I can do it in closed-form?
$$ \int^{2\pi}_0 \cdots \int^{2\pi}_0
\exp\left\{ -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_{n}\left[\sum_{m=n+1}^{N}a_m \cos\left(\theta_{n}-\theta_{m}\right)\right]\right\} d\theta_1 \cdots \theta_N
$$

$$=\int^{2\pi}_0 \cdots \int^{2\pi}_0 \prod^{N-1}_{n=1} \prod_{m=n+1}^{N}\textrm{exp} \left\{
-a_n a_m \cos\left(\theta_{n}-\theta_{m}\right)
\right\} d\theta_1 \cdots \theta_N$$

$$=\int^{2\pi}_0 \cdots \int^{2\pi}_0 \prod^{N-1}_{n=1} \prod_{m=n+1}^{N}\textrm{exp} \left\{
-b_{n,m} \cos\left(\theta_{n}-\theta_{m}\right)
\right\} d\theta_1 \cdots \theta_N$$
where $b_{n,m}=a_n a_m$.

For N = 2, I know that
$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 \textrm{exp} \left\{
-b_{1,2} \cos\left(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}\right)
\right\} d\theta_1 d\theta_2=4\pi^2I_0\left(b_{1,2}\right)
$$ where $I_0\left(\cdot\right)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.